# parameter must have value missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a parent template which has nested templates. Parent Template is master.yaml. It has templateurls defined for nested templates.
one nested template is of load-balancer.yaml and one nested template is of service.yaml.Load-balancer.yaml is creating 2 listeners value in output. Service.yaml has parameters listener and listener2 which i am referring in service.yaml using ref function
For eg:

```
  ListenerRule:
Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
Properties:
  ListenerArn: !Ref Listener
  Priority: 1
  Conditions:
    - Field: path-pattern
      Values:
        - !Ref Path
  Actions:
    - TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
      Type: forward
```

Same is being done for listenerrule2. It is giving error on listener2 parameter must have value.

I have checked references but could not find anything. For Reference sharing load-balancer.yaml and service.yaml where the values are passed.

```
load-balancer.yaml
Outputs:
  Listener:
    Description: A reference to a port 80 listener
    Value: !Ref LoadBalancerListener

  Listener2:
    Description: A reference to a port 443 listener
    Value: !Ref LoadBalancerListener2



 Service.yaml
    Parameters:
      Listener:
        Description: The Application Load Balancer listener to register with
        Type: String

      Listener2:
        Description: The Application Load Balancer listener to register with
        Type: String
```

ERROR: parameter must have value listener2, listener2 value is found in load-balancer output in cloud formation. Let me Mention here i have two listeners,two target groups. one listener for http and one for https. but for testing purpose i am using both as http ports.

Comment: It appears that you wish to pass parameters from the nested stack to the main stack, is that correct? Or is it the other way around? Which bit of code is in the nested stack vs the main stack? Which line in which template is generating the error message? Your question is somewhat confusing to read. Could you possibly edit the question to clarify details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Resolved.

- Was not passing parameter correctly.

  Listener2: !GetAtt ALB.Outputs.Listener2

This is passed is master template Under Alb under parameters section.

Working Like a Charm now